# executable jar file doesnt run upon double click

Tags: java, jar, javac, javaw

so everything was fine like 2 to 3 weeks ago and suddenly my all my jar files couldnt be opened with double clicks

I checked my registry but everything is normal
associated .jar apps to run with javaw
and still i cant get to run executable .jar files on double click

i can run them in cmd with javaw -jar filename.jar
but it doesnt work on minecraft and i cant run minecraft with that cmd i want to make it so every executable .jar file can open with double click

```
               *NOTE*
```

my java command works in cmd
my Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\jarfile\shell\open\command value is:

"C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_311\bin\javaw.exe" -jar "%1" %*
its the same on local machine.
anybody help?

also i used jarfix but it doesnt work and when i click a jar executable mouse just spins for a split second and nothing happens, im trying to fix this for like 4 hours.

Comment: it says Java(TM) Platform SE Binary

Answer (score 0):

Try removing this value from the registry:

```
[-HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.jar]
```

And then the following commands:

```
C:\>assoc .jar=jarfile
C:\>ftype jarfile="C:\path\to\your\javaw.exe" -jar "%1" %*
```

Comment: nope, nothing changed. Still cant open any executable jar file.